# Raising a ValidationError associated with a field in model's `clean` method

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to raise a field bound `ValidationException` in django's models `clean` method?

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def clean(self):
    if self.title:
        raise ValidationError({'title': 'not ok'})
```

The above does not add the error to the `title` field (when using a form), but to the non field errors (`__all__`).

I know how to do it inside a form (`self._errors['title'] = self.error_class([msg])`), but `self._errors` does not exist inside the models `clean` method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the Django docs, this is possible using
[model.clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)

This provides everything you asked for!

The box above the note appears to be what you are looking for:

```
raise ValidationError({
    'title': ValidationError(_('Missing title.'), code='required'),
    'pub_date': ValidationError(_('Invalid date.'), code='invalid'),
})
```

The code parameter is a kwarg and therefor optional. (It's in the example so i've pasted it over)

in your case my guess is you needs something like this:

```
raise ValidationError({
    'title': ValidationError('not ok'),
})
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted. However you do not need to wrap the error message in a second ValidationError, a bare string works fine.

Comment: Note that you can also pass a list in the values of the dict, like this: `raise ValidationError({'title': [ValidationError("one"), ValidationError("two")]})`

Answer (score 2):

You don't, a `Model`'s clean method is only meant for raising `non field errors`, you can however raise a field error by creating a `clean_title` method.

```
def clean(self):
    """
    Hook for doing any extra model-wide validation after clean() has been
    called on every field by self.clean_fields. Any ValidationError raised
    by this method will not be associated with a particular field; it will
    have a special-case association with the field defined by NON_FIELD_ERRORS.
    """
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that, too. But it seems that it must be hooked to the field itself using `validators=[clean_title]`, and therefore `clean_title` must be defined before the field (or must be imported). Not very convenient.

Comment: It's possible to raise field errors from a model's `clean` method, so this answer is incorrect.