# Django model's clean() method not raising the expected ValidationErrors for individual fields

Tags: python, django, validation

I have a Django model called `CheckIn` with (among others) two fields, `min_weeks` and `max_weeks`. I would like to build in validation such that `min_weeks` is always less than or equal to `max_weeks`. Following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddo#django.db.models.Model.clean (in particular, the last example in which the `ValidationError` is passed a dictionary which maps fields to errors), I tried the following `clean()` method:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class CheckIn(models.Model):
    min_weeks = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    max_weeks = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def clean(self):
        if self.min_weeks > self.max_weeks:
            raise ValidationError({
                'min_weeks': ValidationError("'min_weeks' should be smaller than 'max_weeks'", code='invalid'),
                'max_weeks': ValidationError("'max_weeks' should be greater than 'min_weeks'", code='invalid')})
```

The model is used in a `ModelForm`:

```
class CheckInForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CheckIn
        fields = [
            'min_weeks',
            'max_weeks',
        ]
```

The fields are displayed manually in the template. Here is an excerpt:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s4">
    <div class="js-hide-edit-field-text {% if not check_in_type or form.min_weeks.value %}hide{% endif %}">
      {% if check_in_type and not form.min_weeks.value %}
        <span class='js-max-weeks inherited-field text'>{{ check_in_type.min_weeks }}</span>
        <a href='#' class='js-hide-edit-field-edit edit-icon right'><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></a>
        <label class="active">
          Min Weeks
        </label>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="js-hide-edit-field {% if check_in_type and not form.min_weeks.value %}hide{% endif %}">
      {{ form.min_weeks|add_error_class:"invalid"|attr:"data-duration-weeks-mask" }}
      {{ form.min_weeks.errors }}
      {{ form.min_weeks|label_with_classes }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field col s4">
    <div class="js-hide-edit-field-text {% if not check_in_type or form.max_weeks.value %}hide{% endif %}">
      {% if check_in_type and not form.max_weeks.value %}
        <span class='js-min-weeks inherited-field text'>{{ check_in_type.max_weeks }}</span>
        <a href='#' class='js-hide-edit-field-edit edit-icon right'><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></a>
        <label class="active">
          Max Weeks
        </label>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="js-hide-edit-field {% if check_in_type and not form.max_weeks.value %}hide{% endif %}">
      {{ form.max_weeks|add_error_class:"invalid"|attr:"data-duration-weeks-mask" }}
      {{ form.max_weeks.errors }}
      {{ form.max_weeks|label_with_classes }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that there is some additional logic in here to 'inherit' values from the `CheckIn`'s `CheckInType` if they are not provided explicitly. By and large, though, the template is just displaying `form.min_weeks` and `form.max_weeks` and the corresponding errors.

The problem is that if I enter invalid value for `min_weeks` and `max_weeks`, I see a different error message than I would expect (namely, "Enter a whole number" instead of "'min_weeks' should be smaller than 'max_weeks'"):

[image]

This is all the more puzzling because I have entered whole numbers. Any idea what the issue might be here?

Comment: Note you may want to check that `min_weeks` and `max_weeks` are not None before you compare them. `2 > None` gives a `TypeError` in Python 3, and it doesn't really make sense in Python 2.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633813/raise-field-error-in-models-clean-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like passing the `code='invalid'` keyword argument is what causes it to raise this default error message. If I modify the `Model.clean()` method as follows:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.min_weeks > self.max_weeks:
        raise ValidationError({
            'min_weeks': ValidationError("'min_weeks' should be smaller than 'max_weeks'"),
            'max_weeks': ValidationError("'max_weeks' should be greater than 'min_weeks'")})
```

then the errors are displayed as expected:

[image]

Incidentally, the way I tracked this down was by looking at the source code for Django's `IntegerField`, which starts like this:

```
class IntegerField(Field):
    widget = NumberInput
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid': _('Enter a whole number.'),
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

That's not how you raise multiple validation errors while assigning them to fields. You need to use `form.add_error()`:

```
 form.add_error('min_weeks', ValidationError("'min_weeks' should be smaller than 'max_weeks'", code='invalid'))
 form.add_error('max_weeks': ValidationError("'max_weeks' should be greater than 'min_weeks'", code='invalid'))
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'd like to implement the validation at the model level, using the `Model.clean()` method; additionally adding `form.add_error()`s would result in code duplication. Is there any way to 'propagate' the errors raised by the model to the form?

Comment: It's not possible to use `add_error` in a model's `clean` method, unlike a form's `clean` method.