# Raising an ValidationError on a specific field within a clean function in django

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django model and I would like to make validation which involved several of the fields. However I would like to show the validation error on a specific field in the admin page and not globally.

When raising a validationError in the clean function, it always shows the error in the top portion of the admin page see an example:

[image]
I though about using Field validators but because my validations are on the model level and not on the field level it isn't helpful (I only get access to the value of the field and no the whole model instance)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raising a ValidationError associated with a field in model's \`clean\` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633813/raising-a-validationerror-associated-with-a-field-in-models-clean-method)

Answer (score 0):

So I had this same problem today.  I had a mix of non-field errors and field errors that I wanted to all occur in the right place.  And I had trouble finding all the relevant information in the Django docs in one place, but I eventually routed around enough to piece everything together.  (Incidentally, there may be more than one way to do this, and note that I'm working with Django 4.2).

I didn't dig to fully understand the reasoning behind all of this, but my vague understanding is that fields have to be removed from the cleaned data (as processed by `super().clean()`.  Calling `self.add_error(field, error_list)` will automatically remove a field from the `cleaned_data`.  And to add a non-field error, you just supply the `field` argument as `None`.

Here's an example:

```
class myform(Form):
    f1 = CharField()
    f2 = CharField()
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        if "bad" in self.cleaned_data["f1"]:
            self.add_error("f1", ValidationError("invalid f1"))
        if "bad" in self.cleaned_data["f2"]:
            self.add_error("f2", ValidationError("invalid f1"))
        if not (self.cleaned_data["f1"] and self.cleaned_data["f2"]):
            self.add_error(None, ValidationError("Either f1 or f2 must be supplied"))
```

To make them display in the desired places in your template, use `{{ form.f1.errors }}`, `{{ form.f2.errors }}`, and `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` where you want them to go.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [`add_error()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error).

```
self.add_error(fieldname, forms.ValidationError(message))
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the `clean` method of a model, which is what Django admin uses. I think you are thinking of a the `clean` method in a custom form.

Comment: @Flimm Django admin automatically creates a `ModelForm`, if needed you can specify a custom form of your own as well. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form